# kill backend api after UI timeout PHP

Tags: php, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, timeout

I have a PHP backend API that runs snowflake queries.

And the UI is getting timeout in 60 sec. And thus these queries(those runs for more than 60sec) keep getting run in the backend even after a timeout.

Is there any way in PHP to kill the backend API thoroughly after the UI gets timeout?

Or say I want to stop this running queries from the backend once UI reaches timeout.

Answer (score 1):

You can use php's inbuilt function connection_status() & connection_aborted() to check for the connection status. Then you can create the logic based on the response received. Please have a look at the following refrences:

1. [Connection aborted](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_connection_aborted.asp)
2. [Connection Status](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_connection_status.asp)

3.[function to kill snowflake query](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_cancel_query)

Hope it helps...